# Java LinkedList safest way to delete while iterating

Tags: java, collections, iterator

I remember from a while back (I think it was some Java book) that the safest way to delete an element while iterating through a collection is using `iterator.remove`.

```
 while(iterator.hasNext())
 {
    if(it.next().condition())
      iterator.remove();
 }
```

As I cannot find that reference and need a relative quick confirmation, can some java veteran confirm this?

Comment: See the first bullet point here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the *only* legal way to structurally modify a `LinkedList` during iteration.

Any other way of removing an element from a linked list during iteration will (if you're *lucky*) throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html):

> The iterators returned by this class's `iterator` and `listIterator` methods are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the Iterator's own `remove` or `add` methods, the iterator will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`.